# Who is Jesus speaking of in Mark 12:26-27? Who is Jesus referencing as "He" in verse 27?

Tags: mark, names-of-god, tetragrammaton, god-the-father

Who is Jesus speaking of as "He" in the below verse?

What person spoke to Moses?

Mark 12:26-27 (Jesus speaking to the Pharisees, quoting scripture)

> 26 But concerning the dead, that they rise, have you not read in the book of Moses, in the burning bush passage, how **God spoke** to him, saying, *‘I am the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob’?* 27 ***HE*** is not the God of the dead, but the God of the living. You are therefore greatly mistaken.”

Comment: In the original account in Exodus, _the angel of the Lord appeared unto him in a flame of fire out of the midst of a bush_. Then _the LORD_ saw that Moses turned aside to see. Then _God_ called out of the midst of the bush. The 'angel of Yahweh'. 'Yahweh'. and 'Elohim'. Both the 'angel of Yahweh' and 'Elohim' are in the midst of the bush and 'the Lord' is observing from above. I think you need to clarify this detail as part of your question. 'God spoke' in the Greek therefore references 'Elohim' as 'Theos'.

Comment: Jesus and the apostles never taught their disciples about a multi-person God.  No amount of sophistry wil change the truth about the God of Jesus and Jesus. Acts 3:13 is just one of the many verse that shows the apostles and their forefathers never believed and taught a multi person God.

Comment: Speculative opinion based, unwarranted trinitarian dispute topic.

Comment: @Michael16 The question is literally 100% subjective.  Its revealing that you believe a rational question is *"Speculative opinion based, unwarranted trinitarian dispute topic"*.  Please explain your comment.

Comment: The pronoun is used for God. You are just postulating a trinitarian or personhood question, which is more of a systematic theology rather than hermeneutical contextual based question. Such questions are very common here which raises unnecessary trinity debates.

Comment: @Michael16 The question is *Who is the He that spoke?*   That is all.

Comment: It was God, quite apparently, but you are making it into a speculative question of whether it was the Son or the Father.

Comment: Yes.  I am asking who spoke.  Not what spoke.  If you read the answers, Trinitarians are torn between 2.  Did the angel speak declaring himself to be the God of Abraham, OR did the non-personified divinity speak somehow.... ?  What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesus is quoting from the scene in Exodus 3:6 where YHWH is speaking to Moses for the very first time.

> 6 Moreover **HE** said, “I am the God of your father—the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob.” And Moses hid his face, for he was afraid to look upon God.

### **Jesus is speaking of his God and Father - the God of Israel, YHWH - *"the only True God"***.

Many times throughout the gospels Jesus makes a clear distinction between himself and the 1 God.

Here are some examples:John 8:54 Authorized KJV

> Jesus answered, If I honour myself, my honour is nothing: it is ***my Father*** that honoureth me; of whom ye say, that **HE** is **your God(YHWH).**

Luke 4:18 (Jesus reads from a **scroll** in the synagogue.)

> "The Spirit of **YHWH** is upon **ME**, because **HE** hath anointed **ME** to preach the gospel to the poor; **HE** hath sent **ME** to heal the brokenhearted, to preach deliverance to the captives, and recovering of sight to the blind, to set at liberty them that are bruised,"

Matthew 22

> 43 He(Jesus) said to them, “How then does David in the Spirit call Him ‘Lord,’ saying:
> 44 **‘YHWH said to my Lord**, “Sit at My right hand,
> Till I make Your enemies Your footstool” ’?

John 17:3 (Jesus speaking to his God and Father)

> And this is eternal life, that they may know **You, the only true God**, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent.

John 20:17

> Jesus said to her, “Do not cling to Me, for I have not yet ascended to My Father; but go to My brethren and say to them, **‘I am ascending to My Father and your Father, and to My God and your God.’** ”

Jesus speaks so that he can be understood by children with ears to hear.  His words are purposeful and meaningful.  Included in his words are the pronouns he uses to reference the 1 God.

Jesus uses plural personified pronouns when referencing himself and his Father.

John 14:23
King James Version

> 23 Jesus answered and said unto him, If a man love me, he will keep my words: and my Father will love him, and **WE** will come unto him, and make **OUR** abode with him.

Comment: And yet for some reason Jesus “forgets” to include the word “father.” Requiring you to add to Jesus’ words in order to make His “quote” fit.

Comment: @RevelationLad...... as if there exists another ONLY True God.  Who spoke to Moses?

Comment: I’m simply pointing out to how must embellish what Jesus says in order to make it fit your claim of quoting Exodus 3:6. Which really raises the question. If it is abundantly clear, why don’t the two agree? What I mean is if Jesus had used the words you have to put in his mouth, your claim would be spot on…and yet for some reason that which was spoken to Moses is not quoted by Jesus.

Comment: Embellish?  Hardly.  What words am I putting in Jesus' mouth specifically?

Comment: I don’t see father in anything Jesus said.

Comment: @RevelationLad Jesus makes it abundantly clear that his God is his Father.  AND that there is only 1 God, YHWH.  What words did I put in Jesus' mouth?  I'm literally just quoting his words..... Its seems kinda funny to me that a trinitarian is telling me I'm embellishing Jesus' words..... Jesus NEVER claims to be the 1 God ever.  So who is embellishing what exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147567/discussion-between-revelation-lad-and-read-less-pray-more).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the word "He" does not exist in the Greek text at all. Here is my literal translation of the NA28/UBS5 Greek text of Mark 12:27 -

> οὐκ ἔστιν Θεὸς νεκρῶν ἀλλὰ ζώντων. πολὺ πλανᾶσθε. = God is not of
> [the] dead but of [the] living.  You greatly err.

By contrast, the TR text has this:

> οὐκ ἔστιν ὁ Θεὸς νεκρῶν, ἀλλὰ Θεὸς ζώντων· ὑμεῖς οὖν πολὺ πλανᾶσθε.
> God is not of the dead but God of the living. You are therefore
> greatly mistaken.

Note that

- "He" is absent in both cases
- "God" is nominative and thus is the subject of the verb "is".  There can be no doubt that Jesus is discussing Jehovah-God of Israel which is confirmed in the next section.

**Who spoke to Moses?**

The pertinent part of the OT record is quoted below:

> Ex 3:1-7 - **1** Meanwhile, Moses was shepherding the flock of his
> father-in-law Jethro, the priest of Midian. He led the flock to the
> far side of the wilderness and came to Horeb, the mountain of God.
> **2** There the **Angel of the LORD** appeared to him in a blazing fire from within a bush. Moses saw the bush ablaze with fire, but it
> was not consumed. **3** So Moses thought, “I must go over and see this
> marvelous sight. Why is the bush not burning up?”
>
> **4** When **the LORD** saw that he had gone over to look, **God** called out to him from within the bush, “Moses, Moses!”
>
> “Here I am,” he answered.
>
> **5** “Do not come any closer,” **God** said. “Take off your sandals, for the place where you are standing is holy ground.” **6** Then He
> said, “**I am the God** of your father, the God of Abraham, the God of
> Isaac, and the God of Jacob.”
>
> At this, Moses hid his face, for he was afraid to look at **God**.
>
> **7** **The LORD** said, “I have indeed seen the affliction of My people in Egypt. I have heard them crying out because of their
> oppressors, and I am aware of their sufferings.

Note that in this encounter, the person speaking to Moses is variously called (as highlighted above):

- the LORD (= YHWH)
- the Angel of the LORD (YHWH)
- God (Elohim)

The Cambridge commentary observes this concerning Ex 3:2:

> 2. the angel of Jehovah] The ‘angel of Jehovah,’ or, in E (Exodus 14:19, Genesis 21:17; Genesis 31:11), ‘of God,’ is a temporary, but
>    full, self-manifestation of Jehovah, a manifestation usually, at any
>    rate, in human form, possessing no distinct and permanent personality,
>    as such, but speaking and spoken of, sometimes as Jehovah Himself
>    (e.g. v. 4a here, comp. with v. 2; Genesis 16:10; Genesis 16:13;
>    Genesis 31:11; Genesis 31:13; Jdg 6:12; Jdg 6:14; Jdg 13:21 f.), and
>    sometimes as distinct from Him (e.g. Genesis 16:11; Genesis 19:13;
>    Genesis 19:21; Genesis 19:24; Genesis 21:17; Numbers 22:31): cf. Gray,
>    EB. iv., Theophany, § 4. As Davidson remarks (DB. i. 94b, s.v. Angel),
>    the ‘angel of Jehovah’ differs from ‘Jehovah’ only in being sensibly
>    manifest: ‘the mere manifestation creates a distinction between the
>    “angel of Jehovah” and “Jehovah,” though the identity remains.’ The
>    angel of Jehovah is mentioned chiefly in the older parts of the
>    historical books, J, E (never P), and the older narratives in Judges
>    (Exodus 2:1; Exodus 2:4, Exodus 5:23, Exodus 6:11 f., Exodus 20-22,
>    Exodus 13:3-21).

This occurs numerous times in the OT - see appendix below.

**APPENDIX - Angel of the LORD**

The following passages make it clear that the “Angel of the LORD” is almost always, the LORD (Jehovah) Himself.  Gen 16:7-13, 22:11-17, 32:24-30, 48:16, Ex 3:2-6, 32:34, Num 22:22-35, Josh 5:13-15, Judg 2:1-4, 6:11-23, 13:3-23, Isa 63:9, Dan 3:25, 28, Hos 12:4, 5, Zech 3:1-7, Mal 3:1,

A closely related phrase, “Angel of God” who is clearly God as in Gen 6:13, 8:15, 9:8, 17, 15:13, 17:3, 4, 21:12, 16-21, 35:1, 10, Ex 4:3-8, 6:2, 23:20, 21, Deut 1:6, 1 Kings 12:22, etc.  See also Acts 10:3, 4, Gal 4:14.
In Isa 63:9, “the Angel of His [LORD’s] presence saved them”, and is almost certainly a reference to the same being.  The same is true of Ex 23:20, 21, Josh 5:13-15.

In view of the clear statements in John 1:18, 5:37, 6:46, 1 John 4:12 that no one has seen God the Father, and the numerous cases listed above of people seeing the LORD and the Angel of the LORD, etc, it appears that these epiphanies were of the pre-incarnate Jesus.

In other places we see that the LORD sends the LORD:

- Zech 2:6-12 – the LORD (= YHWH) claims three times that He has been sent by the LORD.
- Isa 48:11-16 – again, the LORD has been sent by the LORD.

Comment: What, then, is your interpretation of the greek word ἔστιν in this scripture?  What is the correct pronoun?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - ἔστιν is just the verb "is" - present indicative active, part of the verb "eimi" = "to be".  In this construction the verb is used to define a relationship - God is such of the living and not the dead.

Comment: I don't think I can agree fully with your personal literal translation because the Greek word, θεὸς  is used twice by Mark in this verse.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - see me Greek text above - Θεὸς occurs only once in V27.  The word occurs four times in V26.

Comment: v27  οὐκ ἔστιν ὁ θεὸς νεκρῶν ἀλλὰ Θεὸς ζώντων· ὑμεῖς οὖν πολὺ πλανᾶσθε >>> Textus Receptus uses * θεὸς* twice.

Comment: Let me try to ask in a better way. Is the word ἔστιν in this case, He is, it is, they are, we are, she is? How do you interpret this? –

Comment: I thought you subscribed to the Trinity.  Your answer states that the Father of Jesus is YHWH, the God of Israel.  That's what I believe as well.  The Father is YHWH.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - it is true that Greek verbs do not need an explicit (grammatical) subject if one is not explicit; however, God is nominative here and provides the grammatical subject

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - it is true that Jesus says that God the Father is is heavenly Father (and ours too!)  However, it is easy to show that the father is YHWH as well as Jesus, but that is another subject.

Comment: YHWH is only 1 person according to HIS own words.  *Deut 4:35

To you it was shown, that you might know that YHWH Himself is God; there is none other besides Him.*  Zephaniah 3:17

YHWH your God in your midst, The Mighty One, will save; He will rejoice over you with gladness, He will quiet you with His love, He will rejoice over you with singing.”

Isaiah 42:8

"I am YHWH, that is My name; And My glory I will not give to another, Nor My praise to carved images."

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - this is not the place for debate but nowhere in scripture does it say that YHWH is **one person**.

Comment: If we use the  Textus Receptus then a pronoun appears to be required in the translation.  What Greek manuscripts are you referencing in your answer?

Comment: The fact the *HE* uses *HE* to refer to *HIMSELF* thousands of times clearly makes the case.  HE has 1 personality.  So 1 person.  This is how HE designed HIS creation.  1 person has 1 voice and speaks with a personality.

Comment: I'm very interested in what you have to add to these answers. 
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/96011/trinitarian-ontology-what-is-it-being-vs-person-vs-essence-vs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147566/discussion-between-dottard-and-read-less-pray-more).

Comment: @Dottard.  There is no verse that says the LORD sends the LORD.

Comment: @AlexBalilo - I knew I could count on you for the regular and usual downvote.  Read the text quoted and you will see - if you are honest.

Comment: @Dottard. Read the text that you cited and you will not find,  "the LORD sends the LORD", if you are honest.

Answer (score 2):

> ... how in the bush **God spake** unto him, saying, I am *the* God of Abraham, and *the* God of Isaac, and *the* God of Jacob? - Mark 12:26

God here is *theos* which is a singular, generalized term indicating divinity unless it is paired with the definite article, in which case it refers to **the** supreme Divinity (of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob).

So, according to Jesus, the divinity who spoke to Moses was **the** supreme divinity.

At Exodus 3:4-6 it is Elohim (plural) who speaks to Moses:

> And when the LORD saw that he turned aside to see, **God called unto him out of the midst of the bush**, and said, Moses, Moses. And he said, Here am I.  **And he said**, Draw not nigh hither: put off thy shoes from off thy feet, for the place whereon thou standest is holy ground. **Moreover he said**, I am the God of thy father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob. And Moses hid his face; for he was afraid to look upon God.

Therefore, Jesus refers to the plural divinity (elohim) as the singular divinity (theos) who is *the* supreme divinity and the one speaking to Moses.

In verse 7 it is the LORD (Jehovah) who speaks to Moses through verse 10 and then Moses, in verse 11, responds to Elohim.  Trying to parse out individual persons here is unnecessary, which is why Jesus did not do so.  It is **the** singular, supreme divinity of Abraham, Issac, and Jacob who spoke to Moses and that (single) Divinity is Elohim (plural) and, for Israel, the national name of this singular, plural Divinity is Jehovah.

Comment: Both you are NigelJ are making the case that a non personified divinity can speak with a personality.  Is this the popular Trinitarian view?  Rather than the Father speaking through His messenger?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore No.  The point I'm making is that since Jesus didn't specify which specific person spoke it isn't necessary for us to do so.  No matter which of the three it was that spoke it is accurate to say that Elohim called Moses from the midst of the bush.  Jehovah (single)  saw and Elohim (plural) spoke.

Comment: Personally I can't think of a single verse where Jesus speaks of God as someone other than his Father. If Elohim(plural) spoke, then do you believe all 3 persons of God were speaking in unison to Moses, saying "I am"?

Comment: @MikeBorden. What is the biblical definition of this singular, plural Divinity. Who is/are this/these singular plural Divinity?

Comment: @AlexBalilo "First *elohiym* created."  There is one *theos* and that one *theos* is *elohiym*...  *Elohiym* being the plural form of *eloahh*.  "Let us make man in our image, after our likeness".

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore Well, *Theos* is Jesus' own Father (John 5:18) so that makes sense.   I think that since *Theos* (single)  has  perfect integrity between Being, Word, and Deed there can be no ontological difference between who he is (Father), what He says (Logos/Son), and what He does (Spirit) and that because *Theos* has infinite integrity between the three He is *Elohim* (plural).  That is the best my finite mind can juxtapose the many Scriptures.  "How say the scribes that Christ is the Son of David?"

Comment: @MikeBorden. Does Jesus identify himself and consider himself as one of the referents whenever he mentions the word God?

Comment: Copied from this q: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/46994/52004
*"When God made Moses a god (Elohim) to Pharaoh, Exodus 7:1, was Moses perceived as having a plurality of person within himself?

Was the pagan god Dagon (Elohim) in 1 Samuel 5:7 perceived as having a plurality person within himself?*"

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore This excellent answer to that very question addresses your query:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/47903/32868

Comment: @AlexBalilo I believe that sometimes he does (John 8:42).

Comment: @MikeBorden. You are trying to make Jesus sound like he is equivocating. You are using God to refer to the Father, then use it to "sometimes" refer to an unidentified multi person God (plural divinity) then use God like you are using it the same way.

Comment: @AlexBalilo "If *theos* were your Father you would love me for I proceeded forth and came from *theos*".  These are not my words.  *Theos* is God but not Father to some therefore they are not strictly equivalent for every person in every context.

Comment: @MikeBorden. Is the Father of Jesus not the only true God?

Comment: @AlexBalilo In the end, 1 Cor. 15:24-28, the Son delivers up the kingdom "to God *kai* to Father".  Translations that represent this as God the Father are ignoring this copulative particle.  The Son ultimately will subject himself to the one who put everything under him so that *Theos* may be all in all.  The Father alone is not to be all in all ... it is *Theos* in relationship that is to be all in all; Father over/Son in subjection/united in One Spirit.

Comment: @MikeBorden. Is the Father and God of Jesus not the only true God.. Who placed everything under Jesus?  If the Father/ God is not to be all in all, who is this Theos in relationship that is to be all in all?

Comment: @AlexBalilo Father over/Son in subjection/united in One Spirit.  That is "Theos" from everlasting to everlasting...the God who is all in all.

Comment: @MikeBorden. Where can we find this definition of Theos in the Bible?

Comment: @AlexBalilo Virtually everywhere.

Comment: @MikeBorden. Can you cite one verse please if it is virtually everywhere.

Comment: @AlexBalilo "And we know that the Son of God is come, and hath given us an understanding, that **we may know him that is true** (Father), and **we are in him that is true, even in his Son** Jesus Christ. This is the true God, and eternal life. " - 1 John 5:20

Comment: @MikeBorden. That is different from your previous definition of Theos which you say is *Father over/Son in subjection/united in One Spirit. That is "Theos" from everlasting to everlasting...the God who is all in all.".If as you say this is"found virtually everywhere"why is there no verse that defines it as you define it?

Comment: @AlexBalilo It is the same.  We may know him that is true (Father) and be in Him that is true (Son).  Both Father and Son are **him that is true**.  This is the true God and eternal life: **knowing and being in Him who is true**.  I suspect you may not like this but there is a spiritual enlightening which must occur (1 Corinthians 2:10-16).  We must be given eyes to see and ears to hear and hearts to understand (Matthew 13:10-17).  We must want it badly enough to abandon everything else for the sake of it (Matthew 13:44-46).

Comment: @MikeBorden. Your definition is not the same as the verse you quoted. There  is no verse that defines Theos  like you define it despite your claim that it can be found "virtually everywhere".  How is the bible to be understood if we abandon everything else like perception and reason?

Comment: @AlexBalilo "This is the true God and eternal life"  What is?  Knowing him that is true (Father) **and** being in him that is true (Son).  We don't abandon perception and reason but the perception and reason of the natural man are inadequate (1 Corinthians 2:10-16) until a  spiritual awakening and new birth occurs (John 3:1-10).  Until that happens the Kingdom cannot even be seen let alone entered.  Flesh and blood has not revealed the Christ, the Son of the Living God.  We search the Scriptures for eternal life but they speak of Him.

Comment: @MikeBorden. There is no other God besides the only true God. To say there is another God and that another God is also the only true God is not what the scriptures say. Is the true God  a multi person God?.Who are the natural men whose perception and reason you say are inadequate?

Comment: @AlexBalilo Everyone who has not been born spiritually (born again) is a 'natural man'.  That one is 'in Adam' and not 'in Christ'.  We've already gone far beyond the purpose of comments.  I would be happy to continue in a chat room, if you would like.  I will leave that up to you.

Comment: @MikeBorden. So those who do not agree with your definition of theos are natural men whose reason and perception are inadequate. These natural men are also not born spiritually / again. All these comments still doesn't  truthfully and directly answer where in the bible can we find your definition of theos. Is the only true God of the bible a multi person God?

Answer (score 1):

In the original account in Exodus, the angel of the Lord appeared unto Moses in a flame of fire out of the midst of a bush.

Then the LORD saw that Moses turned aside to see. Then God called out of the midst of the bush.

The 'angel of *Yahweh*' appeared. . . . '*Yahweh*' saw. . . . and '*Elohim*' spoke.

Both the 'angel of *Yahweh*' and '*Elohim*' are in the midst of the bush and 'the Lord, *Yaweh*' is observing from above.

***That demonstrates three persons being present.***

'God spoke', Mark 1:26, therefore references '*Elohim*', in Hebrew, in Genesis, as '*Theos*', in Greek, in Mark.

---

The One manifested (as the 'angel of *Yahweh*') is 'in the midst'.

The One who speaks is 'God' . . . '*Theos*' . . . '*Elohim*'.

The One who oversees, observing, is '*Yahweh*'.

This is reminiscent of Luke 1:35 :

> The Holy Spirit shall come upon thee, and the power of the Highest shall overshadow thee, therefore also the holy-begotten shall be called Son of God; [Young's Literal with one, unnecessary, interpolated, word omitted.]

One overshadows.

One is active.

One is manifest.

And there is, in both circumstances, the life of Deity either in representation (flame) or in reality (begetting) concomitant with what is natural in nature (unburnt bush) or natural in humanity (holy, or 'separated').

It is noteworthy that 'Father' is not referenced in Luke 1:35. But 'Son of God' is. It is the Son of God - his very presence, being 'manifest in flesh' - that is the revelation of 'Father'.

Comment: Thank you @Nigelj  The question is:  *Who is "He" in v27 of Mark 12?*  He is the same who spoke to Moses according to Jesus.  Which person spoke?

Comment: I have answered that question, see above. The One who spoke is 'God' . . . '_Theos_' . . . '_Elohim_'. If you wish to develop this further, we would need a further question, to which I may, or may not, be able to supply an answer.

Comment: @NigelJ. Did Jesus include himself in the Deity "either in representation (flame) or in reality (begetting) concomitant with what is natural in nature (unburnt bush) or natural in humanity (holy, or 'separated').in the verse cited?

Comment: It is the presence of the Son which reveals the Father. And that is the answer to the question of 'Who is Jesus speaking of ?' But without the begetting (of eternal Son to eternal Father) there is no knowledge of the 'Who ?' Thus the relevance.

Comment: @NigelJ. The verse in question says God spoke to Moses. Jesus did not say he spoke to Moses. If as you say  "That demonstrates three persons being present. 'God spoke', Mark 1:26, therefore references 'Elohim', in Hebrew, in Genesis, as 'Theos', in Greek, in Mark." Who are these 3 Persons? Is Jesus included in these 3 persons?

Answer (score 0):

**Mark 12:26 and Exodus 3:6**
Since Jesus places what He says in the context of Moses and the burning bush, the first step is to compare what Jesus says with the event as recorded in the Old Testament and translated to Greek:

> But concerning the dead, that they rise, have you not read in the book of Moses, in the *burning* bush *passage*, how God spoke to him, saying, ‘I *am* the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob’? (Mark 12:26 NKJV)
> `περὶ δὲ τῶν νεκρῶν ὅτι ἐγείρονται οὐκ ἀνέγνωτε ἐν τῇ βίβλῳ Μωϋσέως ἐπὶ τοῦ βάτου πῶς εἶπεν αὐτῷ ὁ θεὸς λέγων ἐγὼ ὁ θεὸς Ἀβραὰμ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰσαὰκ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰακώβ`

> Moreover he said, I *am* the God of thy father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob. And Moses hid his face; for he was afraid to look upon God. (Exodus 3:6 KJV)
> ויאמר אנכי אלהי אביך אלהי אברהם אלהי יצחק ואלהי יעקב ויסתר משה פניו כי ירא מהביט אל־האלהים

> And he said to him, “ I am the God of your father, God of Abraam and God of Isaak and God of Iakob.” And Moyses turned his face away, for he was being reverent to look down before God.
> (LXX-Exodus 3:6 NETS)
> `καὶ εἶπεν αὐτῷ ἐγώ εἰμι ὁ θεὸς τοῦ πατρός σου θεὸς Αβρααμ καὶ θεὸς Ισαακ καὶ θεὸς Ιακωβ ἀπέστρεψεν δὲ Μωυσῆς τὸ πρόσωπον αὐτοῦ εὐλαβεῖτο γὰρ κατεμβλέψαι ἐνώπιον τοῦ θεοῦ`

Jesus follows neither the Hebrew or the Greek accounts. For starters, Jesus did not use the phrase *I **am** the God...*, `ἐγώ εἰμι ὁ θεὸς` as in the LXX. His words were, `ἐγὼ ὁ θεὸς` *I the God...* Since there is no present tense form of the verb *to be* in Hebrew, Jesus preserved the correct Semitic form of self-identification which is simply *I the God...*, `ἐγὼ ὁ θεὸς`, as if He were present.

There are also variances in the use of the article and the conjunction `καὶ`:

```
LXX: ἐγώ εἰμι ὁ θεὸς τοῦ πατρός σου θεὸς Αβρααμ καὶ θεὸς Ισαακ καὶ θεὸς Ιακωβ
Mark: ἐγὼ ὁ θεὸς Ἀβραὰμ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰσαὰκ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰακώβ
```

The Hebrew lists *Abraham, Isaac, **and** Jacob*. The LXX has *Abraham **and** Isaac **and** Jacob*. With respect to `καὶ` Jesus agrees with the LXX. However, unlike the LXX Jesus includes the article with each:

```
LXX:    θεὸς Αβρααμ καὶ   θεὸς Ισαακ καὶ   θεὸς Ιακωβ
Mark: ὁ θεὸς Ἀβραὰμ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰσαὰκ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰακώβ
```

From a purely grammatically point, the construction Jesus employs is how three different would be listed. That is, a list of three items each separated by `καὶ` and each introduced with the article is how distinct items would be written. In this case, what makes the three the same is a belief they are the same, despite grammar which implies otherwise.

The LXX avoided this grammatical implication by omitting the use of the article with Abraham, and Isaac, and Jacob and by ending with `ἐνώπιον τοῦ θεοῦ`. This ending refers back to *He who said*, `εἶπεν αὐτῷ`. In the LXX rendering, *He who said* was He whom Moses *looked down before God*. The ending complements the omission of the articles to make the point He who said "*I the God of...*" was the God who Moses couldn't face, and it is He who was *God of Abraham and God of Isaac and God of Jacob*.

In addition, the LXX properly renders "God" whom Moses cannot look at using the article `τοῦ θεοῦ`. The Hebrew is האלהים, literally ***the** Elohim*. In English the  literal Hebrew is:

> Moreover he said, "I God of your father, God of Abraham, God of Isaac, and God of Jacob." And Moses hid his face; for he was afraid to look upon **the** God.

Exodus in English adds articles where not present, **the** God of Abraham, **the** God of Isaac, **the** God of Jacob, and omits it where it is present, *look down before **the** God.* English translations are contrived to convey the passage as one of clear monotheism. But the ending, ***the** Elohim* suggests otherwise. Arguably, the Hebrew האלהים should be *the Gods* whom Moses could not face. This would agree with the three different descriptions of who was interacting with Moses: the Angel of YHVH (3:2), YHVH (3:4), and Elohim (3:4, 6).

**Mark 12:27**
Jesus explains the significance about what He just said:

> He is not God *of* dead *ones*, but *of* living *ones*. You are greatly mistaken”. (DLNT)
> `οὐκ ἔστιν θεὸς νεκρῶν ἀλλὰ ζώντων πολὺ πλανᾶσθε`

Ironically, the verb expected in the account of God's self-identification at the burning bush, `ἐγώ εἰμι...` is how Jesus begins His explanation. `ἔστιν` is the third person singular of `εἰμι`. It can refer to a person or something. Since translators understand Jesus is referring to God, `ἔστιν θεὸς` is rendered as *he is God*.

There are other considerations. The explanation begins as a negative statement `οὐκ ἔστιν θεὸς νεκρῶν`, *not he is God of dead...*. Also, after using the article before every `θεὸς` in the previous verse, Jesus omits the article in the explanation. Just as in Exodus 3:6, most English translations add the article where none was present.

The initial assumption is God in verse 27 must be referring to God in verse 26. In this case, *God of living* would be *the God of Abraham and the God of Isaac and the God of Jacob*. Of course, Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob **are** dead. Thus there is a paradox in attempting to use the explanation with what Jesus just said.

The paradox is removed when the entire passage is placed into its proper context:

> <sup>18</sup> Then *some* Sadducees, who say **there is no resurrection**, came to Him; and they asked Him...<sup>26</sup> But concerning **the dead, that they rise**...

Concerning Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob and all who are dead, they will rise because there is resurrection and there will be resurrection because there is *God of living*. Therefore, the proper referent to `ἔστιν` is He who is resurrection:

> <sup>23</sup> Jesus said to her, “Your brother will rise again.” <sup>24</sup> Martha said to Him, “I know that he will rise again in the resurrection at the last day.” <sup>25</sup> Jesus said to her, “I am the resurrection and the life. He who believes in Me, though he may die, he shall live. <sup>26</sup> And whoever lives and believes in Me shall never die. Do you believe this?” <sup>27</sup> She said to Him, “Yes, Lord, I believe that You are the Christ, the Son of God, who is to come into the world.” (John 11)

*He* is Jesus. It is He who is the resurrection life of Abraham and Isaac and Jacob, and all who believe. This agrees with Jesus omitting the article. The expression `...ἔστιν ὁ θεὸς...`, that is *He is **the** God*, would be the correct way to clearly connect `θεὸς` in verse 27 with those repeated `ὁ θεὸς` in verse 26. By omitting the article, Jesus makes the distinction between `ὁ θεὸς Ἀβραὰμ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰσαὰκ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰακώβ` and `θεὸς ζώντων`.

Comment: And you told me I was embellishing..... A long and *thorough* answer which is necessary if you are gonna interpret Jesus' words to be declaring himself as the God of Abraham.  Wow good job.  The ambiguity of the Greek language gives one infinite possible concepts if one desires to be prudent.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore No where do I identify *God* in Mark 12:27 with Mark 12:26. Given the varied use of the article that would grammatically inconsistent if not logically impossible. The passage makes the point there is a distinct between God who is responsible for resurrection and the God of Abraham and the God of Isaac and the God of Jacob. They may be the same as you demand (which is inconsistent with the grammar), but as described here, that is not at all what Jesus is saying.

Comment: You are trying to force a rigid monotheistic system into a passage which clearly describes otherwise. Just as with Exodus 3:6, where the literal Hebrew shows more than a single entity is described.

Comment: Your last few comments attempts to make the case for 2 gods.  There is only 1 God.  Also the same comment makes a claim that the *grammar* shows that 1 God is *"logically impossible"*?    Wow amazing.

Comment: *"clearly describes otherwise"*  Right... thats why you needed such a *thorough* grammatical take playing upon the ambiguity of the Greek language to trump the clear statements of my master.

Comment: I notice you think the Trinity is *"grammatically consistent"*....  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/96231/what-pronouns-make-most-sense-when-referencing-the-trinity

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore Again you misunderstand. No where do I say there are two or more Gods. That is how you misrepresent the Trinity. God must be one so the Trinity must be wrong.  You ask a question designed to "prove" your point. But as I show, Jesus makes a **distinction** between `θεὸς ζώντων` (as in resurrection) and `ὁ θεὸς Ἀβραὰμ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰσαὰκ καὶ ὁ θεὸς Ἰακώβ.` The same type of distinction is found in salvation which comes through the blood of Jesus (not the Father's blood). A distinction between Father, Son, and Spirit does not diminish the status of Father, Son, and Spirit.

Comment: You make the case for multiple gods with your words: **"The passage makes the point there is a distinct between God who is responsible for resurrection and the God of Abraham and the God of Isaac and the God of Jacob. They may be the same as you demand**"  Its so crazy to me that all this prudent work is done to satisfy your desire to make Jesus your God even though he says otherwise.

Comment: @RevelationLad. Jesus himself was resurrected by his God. Jesus did not say that he was the God that spoke to Moses. The apostles and their ancestors never taught that Jesus was their God as Acts 3:13-15 show.  If Jesus is God of living, where is his life when he was killed. Can the immortal God be killed?

Comment: @AlexBalilo Nothing is impossible for God. If God can take on human form and offer Himself as a sacrifice for all creation, but chooses not to do so, is an alternative sacrifice which is not God’s best acceptable? And if God offers His best is right for man to diminish what God has done by saying God did not give His best?

Comment: @RevelationLad. It's impossible for God to lie.

Comment: @AlexBalilo In rereading your comment here and elsewhere, I note your inconsistency in explanations. For example, with respect to John 1:1, you claim the use and lack of use of the article is significant to understand what is written. Here, despite places where the use and lack of use of the article is equally significant, your position is, it accounts for nothing. Rather than throwing a word salad of claims, your arguments would benefit from a consistent application of principles, or reasons why what was essential in one place is not so in another.

Answer (score -1):

The context dictates who the "he" is at Exodus 3:2-6. Starting at vs 2, "And the angel of the Lord appeared to him in a blazing fire the midst of the bush; and he  looked and behold, the bush was burning with fire, yet the bush was not consumed.

Vs3, "So Moses said, "I must turn aside now, and see this marvelous sight, why the bush is not burned up." Vs4, When the LORD saw that he turned aside to look, GOD called to him from the midst of the bush and said, (Notice that God is the speaker in the person of the angel of the Lord) "Moses, Moses." And he said, "Here I am."

Vs5, "The HE/God said, Do not come near here; remove your sandals from your feet, for the place on which you are standing is holy ground." Vs6, "HE/God said also, "I am the God of your father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob." Then Moses hid his face, for he was afraid TO LOOK AT GOD."

It is obvious the person being referenced in the question is the AOTL/God. This begs the question? At vs2 it states the angel of the Lord appeared to him/Moses in the midst of the bush." At vs4, the Lord saw that he turned aside to look, GOD CALLED TO HIM FROM THE MIDST OF THE BUSH."

So how does one reconcile God calling from the midst of the bush when the text at vs3 states the angel of the Lord was in the midst of the bush?

We already know from Jesus Himself that God the Father cannot be seen. John 5:37, "And the Father Himself, who sent Me, has testified of Me. You have neither heard His voice at any time, nor seen His form." And John 6:46, "Not that any man hast seen the Father, except he who is from God, he hath seen the Father."

Then another question arises? Why is God using the angel of the Lord to talk to Moses from the midst of the bush when the Lord God at Exodus 20:22 spoke from heaven to Moses. "The then the Lord God said to Moses, Thus you shall say to the sons of Israel, You yourselves have seen that I have SPOKEN TO YOU FROM HEAVEN."

God even spoke from the heavens in the New Testament at Mark 1:11, "and a voice came out of the heavens; "Thou art My beloved Son, in Thee I am well pleased."

In view of all these facts, why is the angel of the Lord introduced to us as speaking for God in the first person? The exact same type of thing happened at Genesis 22 where the angel of the Lord calls out to Abraham two times from heaven and swears an oath to Abraham.

In conclusion, since God the Father cannot be seen the angel of the Lord is the preincarnate Jesus Christ. This is based on the fact that God the Father has no separate manifestation from the Son. The Son is the only manifestation and REVELATION of the Father. What is known of the Father is revealed through the Son. To see the Son is to see the essence of the Father (John 1:1, 18; 10:30; 12:45; Colossians 1:15; Hebrews 1:3) Also, Jesus cannot be an actual angel because angels CANNOT swear oaths on behalf of God Almighty Himself. Genesis 22 is backed up by Hebrews 6:13-18.

Comment: I made my question more clear.  Sorry if it was not before.  I'm asking about "He" in v27 of Mark 12.....  Not about Exodus 3.  *27 HE is not the God of the dead, but the God of the living. You are therefore greatly mistaken.”*  >>>> I think we both can agree this HE is not Moses.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore Oh you made your question clear alright. And I clearly answered your question. Don't you think it would be "prudent" or to do proper Bible study and go to the place that Jesus is referencing at  Mark 12:26 in the Old Testament? Instead, all you did is used this platform to tell us all how Jesus is acting on behalf of God His Father. To be sure that is what Jesus is doing but that was one of the functions of the Messiah. This is why Jesus was sent from heaven to become a man. John 1:14

Comment: You think Moses is speaking to Moses?  You think Moses is the God of Abraham?

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore Oh I get it now, my bad. Now I understand your question? Actually this makes it worse for you because it was not God the Father doing the speaking. First of all, you cannot assume it's the Father which your doing. Secondly, it was the angel of the Lord doing the speaking in the first person and identified as God just like the text/words state. Moreover, the angel of the Lord is the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ. Genesis 22 proves this and in the NT the Father has NO separate manifestation from the Son. What is known of the Father is revealed through the Son. Joh 14:9 John 1:18

Comment: I can interpret Jesus speaking of the 1 God as his Father because of all the verses I referenced in the premise.  An angel is a perfect messenger of God.  God speaks through them therefore God is speaking.

Comment: The angel of the Lord is NOT an actual angel. I can prove from Genesis 22. At vs 11 & 15 you have the AOTL calling out from heaven 2 times. I already showed you that God can call out from heaven Himself. Vs16, and said, "By Myself I have sworn, declares the Lord, because you have not withheld your son, your only son. Vs17. I will greatly multiply your seed as the stars of the heavens etc. If the AOTL is an actual angel he cannot swear oaths on behalf of God. This is backed up at Hebrews 6:13-17. Please read it and read the whole of Genesis 22. I'm not making this up, I'm giving you scripture.

Comment: @Mr.Bond.  What in actuality is the angel of the Lord if he is "not an actual angel" as you claim?

Comment: @AlexBalilo Your question should be, "WHO" in actuality is the AOTL The Hebrew word for angel is "malak" and it means messenger. Men are called malak/angel/messengers and a good example is Malachi 3:1. Behold I am going to send My angel/messenger, and he will clear the way before Me." This is referring to John the Baptist at Mark 1:1-4. Back to Malachi 1:3, and the angel/messenger of the covenant, in whom you delight, behold, He is coming." This is referring to the preincarnate Jesus Christ. Read Judges 2:1, Exodus 20:2, Genesis 17:1-8. Read my answer above. Actual angels cannot swear oaths.

Comment: @Mr.Bond. What in actuality is the angel of the Lord if he is "not an actual angel" as you claim?

Comment: @Mr.Bond Are you gonna edit this answer now that you understand the question?  Moses, is not the God of Abraham.  This is currently your answer.

Comment: @AlexBalilo I just edited my post and in the conclusion  the angel of the Lord is the preincarnate Jesus Christ.

Comment: @Mr.Bond. Why does the bible always identify the angel of the LORD as the angel of the LORD if he is not the angel of the LORD.?

Comment: @AlexBalilo Thats a very good question and I have a very good Biblical answer. The Hebrew word for angel is "malak." This word simply means messenger. As you know angels are messengers, but so are men. Malachi 3:1, Behold, I am going to send My malak/angel/messenger, and he will clear the way before Me. And the Lord, whom, you seek will suddenly come to His temple; and the malak/angel/messenger of the covenant  in whom you delight, He is coming, says the Lord." The first malak is John the Baptist. Read Mark 1:1-4. And he ain't no angel, at least not according to his mother. Continued

Comment: @AlexBalilo Continued. The second "malak/angel/messenger of the covenant who will come to His temple is the Lord Jesus Christ. TAOTL is only in the Old Testament. He is never identified as the AOTL in the New Testament. Although he is mentioned by Stephen at Acts 7. And as a side note, the prophet Malachi who is a human being, well his name is from the word "malak." Does this all make sense to you? Any other questions I will be happy to address.

Comment: @Mr.Bond. So, should it be written as messenger of the LORD? But Jesus did not say that it was he that spoke to Moses, why?

Comment: @AlexBalilo What you doing is asking me to show proof as to why Jesus did not say he spoke to Moses. In logic, this is what is known as an argument from silence. How can anyone present evidence that is NOT stated? Only things that are said is evidence or proof. I have one question for you? Who would you say  appeared to Moses on Mount Sinai in the flame of a burning bush at Exodus 3:1-6?

Comment: @Mr.Bond. I wanted know, what in actuality is the angel of the Lord if he is "not an actual angel" as you claim? Why does the bible always identify the angel of the LORD as the angel of the LORD if he is not the angel of the LORD.? Jesus did say it was God who spoke to Moses. Jesus did not say he was the God that spoke to Moses. What do you mean with your statement "It is obvious the person being referenced in the question is the AOTL/God."? There is nothing in what Jesus said in the verse in question that says he was the God that spoke to Moses.